# Directors and the movies that they DID NOT direct

Tags: knowledge, visual, movies

*This is a list of directors and the movies that they DID NOT direct.*

[image]

---

***Which two movies will replace the question marks?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question marks are replaced with the films:

> **[Network](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074958/)** (1976) and **[Drive](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780504/)** (2011).

Because in each case:

> the pictured director has directed a movie whose **last word in the title** is also the name of a film from the given year to which they are entirely unconnected.
>
>  1. Stanley Kubrick directed *[Paths of **Glory**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050825/)*, while *[Glory](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097441/)* is a 1989 movie by Edward Zwick.
>
>  2. Martin Scorsese directed *[Cape **Fear**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101540/)*, while *[Fear](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116287/)* is a 1996 movie by James Foley.
>
>  And the two unknowns...
>
>  3. David Fincher directed *[The Social **Network**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1285016/)*, while ***[Network](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074958/)*** is a 1976 movie by Sidney Lumet.
>
>  4. David Lynch directed *[Mulholland **Drive**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0166924/)*, while ***[Drive](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780504/)*** is a 2011 movie by Nicolas Winding Refn.